# Android FlingAnimation for ROTATION in opposite clock direction

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation

```
FlingAnimation flingAnimation = new FlingAnimation(pieView, FlingAnimation.ROTATION);
        flingAnimation.addUpdateListener(new DynamicAnimation.OnAnimationUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(DynamicAnimation animation, float value, float velocity) {
                if(velocity < 50f && !animationStarted){
                    flingAnimation.cancel();
                    autoCenterObjectAnimator.start();
                    animationStarted = true;
                }
            }
        });
        flingAnimation.setFriction(0.3f);
        flingAnimation.setStartVelocity(100);
        flingAnimation.setStartValue(500);
        flingAnimation.setMinValue(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        flingAnimation.setMaxValue(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        flingAnimation.start();
```

I am using the new FlingAnimation from the support library 26.1.0. 
I am not able to rotate the circle to opposite of clockwise. It just rotates in clockwise, no matter which values I pass.

How can I rotate the view in both directions ?

Comment: I would think it was because you are always using a positive start velocity

Comment: I changed the value. So when the velocity is negative, nothing rotates. If its positive it has a velocity to rotate the view.

startValue is just the start value of the rotation. min- and maxValue are just the bounds, where the animation will be stopped. In this case it rotates till the friction stops the fling.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**:

Create an **invisible view** like the

> Space widget

view in your layout and pass it to the FlingAnimation. Nothing will happen of course, but through the update callback you can get the values and pass it to your taget view and let rotate it. By doing the values negative or positive you decide in which direction the rotation will made.

Answer (score 0):

This is also doable with the SpringAnimation. See link with sample code.

[SpringAnimation - Rotation in both directions](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/springanimation-examples)